# Issue on Selecting Child Element Using .focus() Function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove ONLY error div which associated with a specific input on .focus() function. following code works fine but the only problem is , it is removing all `.err` classes regardless of only focusing on `myname` input.

```
 $(':input[name="myname"]').focus(function(){
    $('.err').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
 });
```

I tried to update the selector to `$('.nameinput > div.err').` as the `.err` is inside the `.nameinput` class but it doesn't work

```
 $(':input[name="myname"]').focus(function(){
    $('.nameinput > div.err').fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
 });
```

I also tried the `.closest()` which it didnt work again! can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

************  ***Update***  ***********************

Please take a look at sample code [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/Nqke8/)

Comment: It's really hard to answer this without seeing the html structure.

Comment: We can guess many things, but we'd better wait for OP to give the HTML and not encourage wild guesses.

Comment: OK I am trying to create a JSFIDDLE link for that

Comment: Can you please take a look at following link http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/Nqke8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `err` is the next `div` after the `div` containing your `input`.  Try this:

```
$(':input[name="myname"]').focus(function(){
    $(this).closest("div").next('.err').fadeOut(1000, function() {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nqke8/1/

This will also work for your other `input` if you remove the name restriction:

```
$(':input').focus(function(){
    $(this).closest("div").next('.err').fadeOut(1000, function() {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nqke8/2/

Comment: Can you please also let me know how to resize the form containar smoothly after .focus() I maen if you take a look at this updated link http://jsfiddle.net/Proweb/Nqke8/3/ I wrapped the form inside a div which is re sizing ugly on focus methos!

Comment: I would just use `hide` or `slideUp` instead of `fadeOut`.